# Can't implement library, Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons

i am trying to use the apache commons library to upload image using ftp but i keep getting this error every time i run the app.
The error is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

my build.grandle file look like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.david.six_month"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'

}
```

What is the issue?
I tried clean project and rebuild but nothing seems to be workin..

Comment: Did you happen to add a JAR file to the libs folder?

Comment: Yes i did commons-net-3.6.jar

Comment: Remove it... The `implementation` line is a direct conflict with it